# Can the skin / copper oxide / copper junction of an old exposed mains conductor produce a safety-significant DC component to a shock?

Tags: safety, rectifier

Copper oxide diodes are not common now but were a standard item along with selenium oxide for early power rectifiers (think old radios and those components with stacks of fins).

Can the oxide layer on an old, exposed copper mains conductor provide any significant amount of (pulsed) DC component to an individual who accidentally touches it and is sufficiently grounded that they draw an AC current sufficient to be dangerous?

AC and DC currents have different physiological effects on nerves and muscles so a question about the distinction may be relevant, but here I'm only asking if the skin / copper oxide / copper junction would provide enough rectification to have to be considered separately from a pure AC scenario.

---

Background on copper oxide rectifiers:

- [The Copper Oxide Rectifier](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/294259463_The_Copper_Oxide_Rectifier)
- [Applications and Characteristics of Copper-Oxide Rectifiers July 1933 Radio-Craft](https://www.rfcafe.com/references/radio-craft/copper-oxide-rectifiers-july-1933-radio-craft.htm)
- [The Copper Oxide Rectifier](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.1745338?journalCode=phy) (1936, paywalled)

YouTube:

- [(#0062) Selenium & Copper Oxide Rectifiers - Different Types & I-V Curves](https://youtu.be/_3pN-m_8PgI?t=878)
- [Antique Tech: Copper Diodes, Solenoids, Shading Coils, and Lionel Trains](https://youtu.be/yP89xhVLK9o?t=237)

Comment: I don't know about the copper-oxide ones. But the selenium rectifiers found in my old WW II (1944 commissioned) radar units were painted to insulate them against accidental touching. I know for a fact that I didn't get shocked when touching them while the power was operating. (But they were painted/anodized.)

Comment: That just means I'm not sure what you are asking, then. My reading comprehension is at question. Regarding "pay-walled" anyone can take a DOI and go to Sci-Hub.se and look it up, free.

Comment: As I said, that's my problem then. Not yours. Don't worry about it.

Comment: I wasn't the vote. If you feel there is a problem, stop telling me how simple and easy it is to understand and work on it. If you don't feel there is a problem and the vote is just some random mistake and your writing is perfectly fine, then just ignore me and the vote. It's none of my nevermind.

Comment: @jonk  I remember the selenium diodes well, and I've never seen copper oxide diodes, but apparently they were common, at least for some applications.

Comment: I only date back to WW II units. I also never saw the copper oxide devices. I did read the article, "The Copper Oxide Rectifier" by Chauncey Starr, though. Thanks for that link. It was enjoyable.

Comment: I think I've seen CuO rectifiers Lonnnnnnnng ago. I'd **SUSPECT** that they are such a poor rectifier (high leakage, liable to break down informally formed ones at significant potential, ...) that the AC effects would vastly predominate. Back of brain suggests you'd want say 10% or better DC component to start to make a difference at currents around the area that started to matter. I may well be wrong.

Comment: Downvotes happen. People most often do not say why. My +1 negates it.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon thanks; sometimes there are unwarranted avalanches (for lack of a better term) Oh that's right I see you've recently been "upgraded" to diamond, my goodness it's quite a task! :-)

Comment: @uhoh "diamond"  is far closer to purgatory than one may have imagined :-) :-(> The aim was to help people - but a lot or the resource is taken up by attempting to herd fractious adult cats :-). [And I still only have a +1 to give per answer or question :-) ]

Comment: Without a capacitor to filter the ripple, will the DC component be significant compared to the AC in the ripple ?

Comment: @AJN it's a very good question and I don't know. An answer here can address the rectification; would the "skin / copper oxide / copper" junction "provide any significant amount of (pulsed) DC component" but the details of how that affects a person wouldn't be addressed here.

Comment: Assuming only half wave rectification and no filtering, the DC component seems to be [\$V_{peak}/\pi\$](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/315184). Expression can be derived for the AC component(s) also (Fourier series). That will give an idea of the relative voltages.

Comment: @AJN that's for a theoretical diode right? The hard part is estimating how much if any rectification will actually happen in this circuit with a poor diode.

Comment: You are correct. This is what we can expect "at-most"; an upper bound.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon high question rate sites are very very different than the lower-rate ones. When they are too big/fast it's impossible to build a sense of community and so community moderation is limited to flags and close votes. When the "rooms" are smaller and users recognize each other more, there's pressure and/or incentive for people to become more helpful to each other, the site, new users, and most importantly to the moderators. I wrote [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12734) a while ago on another high Q-rate site. Don't know how to *apply* that here, at least short term.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon For this SE question, I'm thinking that the skin / copper oxide / copper junction might be too "edge case" for most users here and difficult to figure out how to model as a diode. I'm thinking that I should refactor this as a Physics SE question; either asking that part separately there, or (perhaps better) deleting here and posting a new question there. The problem with migration in this case is that it might need to be rewritten first to "physics it up" a bit.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I guess I really want to ask about the conductivity from skin to copper oxide since from there to metal is well known (or was well known a long time ago, these days maybe not so much) Maybe the DC vs AC part is superfluous. I suppose I included it for context/relevance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copper oxide does introduce measurable nonlinearities - so your concern is warranted.

However, we can quickly, from systems where there's a lot of AC voltage *intentionally* brought onto copper parts (namely, broadcast and cellular transmitter stations), gather from the severity of the PIM (passive intermodulation) that the energy in these rectified parts isn't severe enough to be harmful to someone touching a piece of conductor connected to an "accidental copper diode" where not 1 kW of RF is pumped through...

Another aspect: these diode junctions have breakdown voltages in the region of 1 V. By itself, a diode of that type can't sustain a potential difference greater than 1 V; so no risk.
 There would have to be *a lot* of factors coming together (like... an old-school metal-oxide layered disk stack diode) to yield dangerous voltages.

You can safely ignore this, and worry more about other occupational hazards.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In order to understand your analogy, I'd like to ask if the "1 kW of RF is pumped through..." a layer of copper oxide? I just want to double check that you are referring to RF being (weakly) rectified by passing through a path which contains a point where there is no copper-to-copper contact in parallel, or if there is some but there is also a parallel path that passes through oxide. In my question, the person (unfortunately) completes a circuit and draws current *through* the oxide layer.

Comment: yep, if you connect a copper waveguide to another copper waveguide, and on the interface of these two, there's an oxide layer, you'll have a lot of current pass through that oxide layer (lest you do *very* clever things with your waveguide, but that leads too far into the land of fancy flanges and fearfully frightening fractal costs)